# Why is the vibration of chemical bonds quantized but the rotation about single bonds in molecules is not?

Tags: quantization

Vibration of bonds molecules is quantized.  Rotation of entire molecules is quantized. Rotation about single bonds in molecules is not quantized.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about something like an hydroxl group on an ethanol molecule, rotating about the axis of the C-O bond?